# How to programmatically add a custom template that appears in Site Editor from a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to add custom template for FSE (Full Site Editing) from a plugin, but I have no idea how to do it.

I want to make a template for custom post type. that can be edit it from Site Editor.
[image]

I know how to add custom template from `theme.json`. But how can I achieve that from a plugin?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/397925/edit) to tell us what you've tried and what *specific* problem you're having.

Comment: I don't think, there is a need for any details. The question is clear. I have no idea how to do it. So I did not try anything. the problem is clear. how to do something...

Comment: This isn’t off topic. They’re asking about the full site editing features in WordPress 5.8.

Comment: Ah, OK. (Clarifying what FSE stands for might be a good edit for the question.)

Comment: Agreed that it is not off-topic but the OP should explain what their research has uncovered and where they are stuck, asking a specific and answerable question.   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what about now?